# How do I get Solr back up when indexes are locked and <unlockOnStartup>true doesn't work?

Tags: solr

I have a Solr slave that is running in Tomcat. I added a core, so I changed solr.xml. To reload it I decided to simply restart Tomcat using the Windows Services managament console.

After restarting Tomcat I keep getting the following exception:

> org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Index locked for
>   write for core

I decided to temporarily change the solrconfig.xml for each core to add:

```
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
```

But no luck. Locking is set to native, so I can't go and remove lock files.

1. How do I get Solr up and running again?
2. How should I restart Solr to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the index directory and restart solr. It will work

Comment: Where can I find index directory?

Comment: Inside your solr core folder there will be a directory named data and within that there will be a folder named index

Comment: For others...I found files in ./example/solr/collection1/data/index/write.lock
./example/solr/development-edit/data/index/write.lock
./example/solr/development-live/data/index/write.lock

Answer (score 6):

Delete only **write.log** in data/index . Where is data directory is specified in conf/solrconfig.xml.

Comment: In case you are running as SolrCloud with HDFS, then the write lock is on hdfs path, and can be found via admin UI in location -> hdfs dfs -rm /my/path/write/lock

Answer (score 3):

Delete file `write.log` in folder `/data/index/` for your core then restart tomcat. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case the other answers don't work, check your file permissions. In my case, I had to do a

`chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 /opt/solr/corename`

Answer (score 1):

Just deleted write.lock file under Solr > My Core > data > Index > write.lock file and restart solr server and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

My experience as I was a bit confused by the `write.log` with the `.log` ending in some answers (I was expecting a `.lock` ending).

I simply followed the instruction given by Solr:

> Index dir '/var/solr/data/coreName/data/index/' of core 'coreName' is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server)

Then I went to the directory `/var/solr/data/coreName` I searched `find . -iname '*lock'` and then delete those files that were clearly lock files.

Restarted solr and it worked.